# Azure: Deploy Functions app from a project in a solution using VSTS

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have a Functions project called `SomeApp.Func` in a solution containing multiple projects.

When I try to run VSTS online build it fails at MS Build step saying:

`only one project can be specified`

MS Build arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"
```

Tried adding `t:/SomeApp_Func` and `t:/SomeApp.Func`, same error.

Comment: Did you build more than one solutions in VS Build task? And you can show the detail log for Azure App Service Deploy task by setting variable `system.debug` as `true`?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by having these arguments to the ms build task
`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"`

In the release definition I'm using a **deploy azure app service task**, selected **functions** in the type and made sure the **path is mapping to the zip file**.

I had similar issues when having multiple SharePoint Add-ins projects in the same solution, **usually when VS does that, I either make multiple sln files containing at most one kind of the project I'm working on, and then add multiple build tasks pointing to these separate solutions or I only add multiple build tasks pointing to the project files**.